# CSS: How to select last child of a parent based on the child's class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to change the color of text `5` to red.

This doesn't work. What is the possible resolution to this problem?

**Note**: This is a small representation of the actual problem. So the placement of children is not fixed, nor their numbers.

```css
#parent>.child:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span class="child">1</span><br>
  <a>2</a><br>
  <span class="child">3</span><br>
  <a>4</a><br>
  <span class="child">5</span><br>
  <span>6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @TimGerhard - does not seem to work either

Comment: Nope. It'll not work, since `.child` is not the last child.

Comment: the short answer is you cannot not as last-child is the last span whataver you will do and whataver the class you use

Comment: This is not the duplicate as the last child is a span in my case. Please read the question carefully @TemaniAfif

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal it's a perfect duplicate :) you want to select based on a class which is the same as the other question

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal same logic with last-child or last-type ;)

Comment: Okay. I think, there is possibly no solution with CSS. Sad! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
#parent span:nth-child(9) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span class="child">1</span><br>
  <a>2</a><br>
  <span class="child">3</span><br>
  <a>4</a><br>
  <span class="child">5</span><br>
  <span>6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The value of n is not fixed. This is a small representation of the actual problem.